Formatted Text not rendering correctly after import unless field is "clicked"
I'm rendering a  "formatted, long text" field data in a custom template with {{ content.field_short_bio_rich }}.
After a migration import, the HTML is being escaped. For example, Hello becomes <bold>Hello</bold>.
The strange thing is that, after clicking on the field content on the node edit form, it correctly renders the HTML.

It maybe needs to be just <b> or <strong>. Double-check the text format. You maybe need to add <bold> to the allowed tags. Or you need to replace all <bold> tags during migration. It's maybe CKE5 that automatically does the replace when you manually click it.

HTML5 doesn't have a <bold> tag, so it makes sense that it's not allowed by default.
